# successful spacy installation on mac m1, unsuccessful import

Tags: macos, installation, spacy

Specs
**macOS** Monterey (v 12.5.1 (21G83))
**Python** 3.8.12

I was able to properly install spacy on a conda environment.
[image]

However, when trying to import from jupyterlab notebook, I keep getting a kernel restart error.

```
The kernel for notebook.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

Anyone else experiencing this error?
I tried re-installing/creating a new environment with spacy using this thread for mac m1 but it still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution/Alternative:
Update Python version to Python **3.10.4**

1. Create a new environment,
2. install using the commands [here](https://spacy.io/usage) after selecting options based
   on machine specifications. (used conda env instead of venv)